# compressing file by independent chunks and then concat them into one valid archive

Tags: java, compression, gzip

I wonder if it is possible to compress an arbitrary file (or folder, or any other file structure) by independent chunks and then get a valid archive (e.g. gzip) by concatenating them together. Some requirements:

- java 8
- chunks <= 16MB
- folder structure does not change during the process
- chunks are compressed independently, but order is preserved
- each compressed chunk is appended to the end of the resulting archive
- resulting archive should be valid and decompressable by any standard tool

It looks like to achieve that I would need to create an archive header first and then just append compressed blocks to it https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1952, however I'm not sure if it is supported by any of standard java utils or 3rd party libraries. Does anybody have any ideas on where to start from?

Some background:
I have a client-server app, which allows user to upload files to a cloud storage. Communication via REST api, client side is going to be responsible for dividing files into chunks and upload them one by one. It is possible to do compression in browser, however I wonder if we can move that load to the backend.

Comment: If gzip compression is useful for your particular workload (e.g., text instead of images), then doing it client-side is almost certainly a better option. gzip is insanely cheap, and bandwidth savings on client uploads are always helpful.

Comment: workload is arbitrary, text, images, backups, total size is from couple megabytes to many gigabytes. I had a little experience with client side compression, however not sure if compressing a chunk, uploading and then disposing from the memory is supported by any js library (at least quick look at JSZip api didn't clarify that), that actually seems to be the same problem.

Comment: Gzip is normally used to compress just single files, but I think it should be possible to compress a file structure into a single tar archive, and then compressing that archive with gzip. Another alternative would be to use the Zip format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. A concatenation of gzip files is a valid gzip file, per the standard (RFC 1952). gzip certainly handles this.

You are correct to be concerned that some code out there might not support it, since it is not very common to have concatenated gzip members. If you want to be super-safe, you can combine the gzip files into a single gzip member, without having to recompress. You do however need to read through all of the compressed data, effectively decompressing it in memory (which is still much faster than compressing). You can find an example of that in [gzjoin.c](https://github.com/madler/zlib/blob/master/examples/gzjoin.c).

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this for tar + gzip:

Maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-compress</artifactId>
    <version>1.18</version>
</dependency>
```

Java code to compress into chunks:

```
import org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.tar.TarArchiveEntry;
import org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.tar.TarArchiveOutputStream;
import org.apache.commons.compress.compressors.gzip.GzipCompressorOutputStream;
import org.apache.commons.compress.utils.IOUtils;

import java.io.*;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

[..]

private static final int MAX_CHUNK_SIZE = 16000000;

public void compressTarGzChunks(String inputDirPath, String outputDirPath) throws Exception {
    PipedInputStream in = new PipedInputStream();
    final PipedOutputStream out = new PipedOutputStream(in);
    new Thread(() -> {
        try {
            int chunkIndex = 0;
            int n = 0;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
            do {
                String chunkFileName = String.format("archive-part%d.tar.gz", chunkIndex);
                try (OutputStream fOut = Files.newOutputStream(Paths.get(outputDirPath, chunkFileName));
                     BufferedOutputStream bOut = new BufferedOutputStream(fOut);
                     GzipCompressorOutputStream gzOut = new GzipCompressorOutputStream(bOut)) {

                    int currentChunkSize = 0;
                    if (chunkIndex > 0) {
                        gzOut.write(buffer, 0, n);
                        currentChunkSize += n;
                    }
                    while ((n = in.read(buffer)) != -1 && currentChunkSize + n < MAX_CHUNK_SIZE) {
                        gzOut.write(buffer, 0, n);
                        currentChunkSize += n;
                    }
                    chunkIndex++;
                }
            } while (n != -1);
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // logging and exception handling should go here
        }
    }).start();

    try (TarArchiveOutputStream tOut = new TarArchiveOutputStream(out)) {
        compressTar(tOut, inputDirPath, "");
    }
}

private static void compressTar(TarArchiveOutputStream tOut, String path, String base)
        throws IOException {
    File file = new File(path);
    String entryName = base + file.getName();
    TarArchiveEntry tarEntry = new TarArchiveEntry(file, entryName);
    tarEntry.setSize(file.length());
    tOut.putArchiveEntry(tarEntry);

    if (file.isFile()) {
        try (FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(file)) {
            IOUtils.copy(in, tOut);
            tOut.closeArchiveEntry();
        }
    } else {
        tOut.closeArchiveEntry();
        File[] children = file.listFiles();
        if (children != null) {
            for (File child : children) {
                compressTar(tOut, child.getAbsolutePath(), entryName + "/");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Java code to concatenate the chunks into a single archive:

```
public void concatTarGzChunks(List<InputStream> sortedTarGzChunks, String outputFile) throws IOException {
    try {
        try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile)) {
            for (InputStream in : sortedTarGzChunks) {
                int len;
                byte[] buf = new byte[1024 * 1024];
                while ((len = in.read(buf)) != -1) {
                    fos.write(buf, 0, len);
                }
            }
        }
    } finally {
        sortedTarGzChunks.forEach(is -> {
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // logging and exception handling should go here
            }
        });
    }
}
```